# Run script when virtual interface is up

Tags: network-interface, ethernet, virtual-interface

I have  /sbin/ifup-local  set to execute and it works 
but my virutal interface eth0.2 (vlan2) is the one that gets the IP address I need to run the script .
How can i run a bash script when eth0.2 is up ?

I renamed  /sbin/ifup-local to  /sbin/ifup-eth0.2 and it not work

Using Centos6

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this with an initscript (script file under /etc/init.d/), using LSB tag "Required-Start" with "$network" parameter:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: After network script launching
# Required-Start: $network
# Required-Stop: $network
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: start a network dependent script
# Description: Network dependent script launcher
### END INIT INFO
```

Use the [skeleton](https://gist.github.com/ivankovacevic/9917139) here is you haven't your.

Then modify the "do_start()" function to launch your script, for example:

```
do_start()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been started
    #   1 if daemon was already running
    #   2 if daemon could not be started

    cd /my/script/dir && ./myScript.sh

    # Add code here, if necessary, that waits for the process to be ready
    # to handle requests from services started subsequently which depend
    # on this one.  As a last resort, sleep for some time.
}
```

You should modify the "do_stop()" function too to avoid possible shutdown errors.

Comment: And how would this run when the interface comes up, as opposed to when booting the system after the network service has been started?

Comment: yes i was going to say ..........

Comment: Script run after network, so its eth0.2 would be up